# CSS Vertical-align:middle doesn't work

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    height:100px;
}
.wrap tr {
    width:30%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 20px;
    border:1px solid black;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="wrap">
<tr>
    <th><h1>Design Your Bag</h1></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><img src="CMBlogo.gif" style="height:100px;width:100px;" alt="logo"></th>
</tr>
<tr id="right">
    <th><h2><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;Live Help!</h2>
    <h4>(202)-629-3053</h4>
    <h4><a href="mailto:brian@metrologo.com" subject="Contact and Order Information">brian@metrologo.com</a></h4></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

QUESTIONS: when i try to make the images and text in each tr vertical center, nothing happens... I search a lot of similar question online, and try to use ,or "line-height", and float left/right/center. still can not make it works...maybe there is some minor misunderstanding or mistakes I don't realize..please help me..

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfelda/ocykt04h/)  Copied into fiddle, seems to be vertically centered.

Comment: If my answer hasn't helped you, unfortunately it is because I do not understand exactly what you are asking. Please edit this question and be more specific as to how you want what aligned.

Comment: oh..I want each element in its div will be in the center of space . I mean "logo" image will have the same distance to the sides(top bottom right and left)...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your table row elements are vertically aligned in the middle. If you want your entire table to align vertically on the page do the following:

```css
html, body{ margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width:100%; }
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY( -50% );
}
.wrap tr {
    width:30%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 20px;
    border:1px solid black;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
<table class="wrap">
<tr>
    <th><h1>Design Your Bag</h1></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><img src="CMBlogo.gif" style="height:100px;width:100px;" alt="logo"></th>
</tr>
<tr id="right">
    <th><h2><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;Live Help!</h2>
    <h4>(202)-629-3053</h4>
    <h4><a href="mailto:brian@metrologo.com" subject="Contact and Order Information">brian@metrologo.com</a></h4></th>
</tr>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```